# Ruby String/Array Write program

Tags: ruby

I have to write a program in ruby programming language which prints the longest name among others,use the split method,size max ,length.

This is what I have so far:

```
name = gets.chomp.split 
name.each do |x| 
  puts x.size 
  for i in 1..x.size do 
    puts i.max 
  end 
end
```

Comment: what you do for this?

Comment: name=gets.chomp.split
name.each do |x| 
puts x.size
for i in 1..x.size do
puts i.max
end
end

Comment: Are you allowed to use `max_by`? It would make this very easy, and would be more idiomatic than searching for the max value with your own loop.

Comment: the program isn't true

Comment: This is pretty easy. Where are you stuck? Give us real code with input values and desired output and how your and the desired output differ.

Answer (score 3):

Use a a variable which is initially an empty string.

```
max_name = ""
```

When you are inside the loop, check if each `x.size` is larger than `max_name.size`. If that is the case, you have found a new max_name, so do `max_name = x`.

Answer (score 2):

The code fails when trying to get the maximum of the integer `1`. That's an odd-looking guess at the correct code, and means you should probably revise how Ruby's blocks work (you appear to be expecting an interaction between the `max` and `each` that really doesn't exist).

The usual way to get the maximum of something from a list, if you are not allowed to use built-ins, is to set a "current maximum" value and then scan through the list, checking each item to see if it is larger than the current. If it is, set the current value to that instead. At the end, you will have the largest item.

```
name = gets.chomp.split 
current_max = ''
name.each do |x| 
  if x.size > current_max.size
    current_max = x
  end
end
puts current_max
```